# Can't Access the BIOS

Tags: boot, bios

For some reason, my computer will boot and run Windows (only OS) fine but when I spam the delete key on startup to enter the BIOS my computer turns on but nothing appears on the screen (my monitor stays in power saving mode). I have an ASRock X99X Killer motherboard and the Dr. Debug code of A6: *Problem with IDE or SATA devices: clear CMOS and remove all SATA devices.*

I tried to:

- Switched to BIOS B but neither BIOS seems to work
- Cleared the CMOS (99% sure it worked) and replugged in the SATA cables but this did not work
- Tried using the ASRock Restart to UEFI application on the OS itself but this did not help either.

There was not a problem when I installed the OS a year ago but now I can't get back into the BIOS to change settings. I was hoping to get some advise. Should I take out and put back in the BIOS battery?

If you need more clarification on the situation feel free to ask. Thanks to everyone for their time and help!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Common mistake some members make is formatting. Many people will not read a huge bock of difficult to read text. Taking a minute to [edit] your question to make it easier to read will increase your chances of getting the help you seek. Also, signatures are not needed here since the site does it for you.

Comment: Have you tried booting with just the the power, Keyboard mouse and screen and seeing if you can get to the bios?